# Get from cloud firestore?

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

How to get "Comment" data from a cloud firestore.

```
private void iniRvComment() {
    DocumentReference docRef = firestore.collection("Comment").document(postKey);
    docRef.collection("Comment").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (documentSnapshot != null && !documentSnapshot.getDocuments().isEmpty()) {
                listComment = new ArrayList<>();
                List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = documentSnapshot.getDocuments();
                for (DocumentSnapshot value : documents) {

                    Comment comment = value.toObject(Comment.class);
                    listComment.add(comment);
                }
                commentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listComment);
                RwComment.setAdapter(commentAdapter);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I used the code from the official Firebase website but this code does not work or I didn’t write it correctly, I use "postId" as the key. How to get the whole "Comment" so that it is displayed under each "Post"
Comment document:

[image]

Post document:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmulv.png)

Comment: In the first line you say `firestore.collection("Comment").document(postId)` and that should be `firestore.collection("Post").document(postId)`.

Comment: No, sorry, fixed "postId" to "postKey". I want to get "Comment", if "Comment (postKey) ==" Post (postId) "then I need to display Comments under the current post

Comment: Ah... so `Comment` is a top-level collection? I missed that.

Comment: yes. 
You know how to do it?

Comment: @ArmanAbdullin Is the value of `postKey` equal to `ZQMq ... 7MY2`? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: There is a post, under each post the user leaves a comment. I want to make a comment if it belongs to

Comment: set the post with document (
ZQMqIrx19fftjO3ZeSzkuEw87MY2), if another user leaves a comment under this post then it is set to postkey (
ZQMqIrx19fftjO3ZeSzkuEw87MY2) too.